# Sharing a partial from a different namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview

`rails 6.1`

I am wanting to reference a partial in `app/views/shared/` from another namespace.

```
# app/views/something/index.html.erb
<%= render partial: 'shared/my_partial' %>
# looks for app/views/shared/_my_partial.html.erb

# app/views/admin/something/index.html.erb
<%= render partial: 'shared/my_partial' %>
# looks for app/views/admin/shared/_my_partial.html.erb
```

When calling from within a namespace, the path always seems to be nested within that namespace, and cannot look outside of itself.

I have found this PR https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/22473 which would allow for denoting a leading `/` or `./` to specify absolute path, but it appears to be unmerged for many years which doesn't fill me with hope.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this apart from duplicating the views?

Answer (score 0):

There are no issues here, just a lack of understanding on how operating system paths work.
To solve, just add a leading '/' to the path `<%= render partial: '/shared/my_partial' %>`
But a nicer syntax is just to use

```
<%= render '/shared/my_partial' %>
```

You no longer need the full partial syntax

Answer (score -1):

Well it appears I've been able to resolve this by using `render('path/to/partial')` rather than `render(partial: 'path/to/partial')`.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.1/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-an-action-s-template-from-another-controller

I am pretty confused as to why this method was not mentioned on any of the dozen articles I read trying to solve this issue, and I'm even more confused why the behavior between the two syntaxes varies so fundamentally.

Comment: You don't need to do that